# Microsoft Dynamics Nav access web services remotely

Tags: web-services, navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2015

I have installed Microsoft Dynamic Nav 2015 on Windows Server 2012 and I'm trying to use Navision web services from another network, but it says the server took too long to respond (meanwhile i can easily access web services locally). What am i missing?? I also opened the ports used by Navision on firewall settings. I cant really find a good tutorial how to consume Navision web services externally. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Where exactly it "says" the error? Have you tried it just in browser?

Comment: Presumably you can ping the server from the other network...  Have you tried [using telnet](http://blog.industrialnetworking.com/2011/09/using-telnet-to-test-open-ports.html) to test if the web service port is also visible?

Comment: How are you "trying to use Navision web services"?

Do you have a visual studio project to which you are trying to add a service or web reference?

From "another network" have you tried using the external ip address to see if you can even access the server on which you are running the nav services?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a walkthrough on consuming nav web services if that's what you're after:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd339004(v=nav.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are accessing the service from 'another network' make sure that both your Windows firewall, and your router firewall are configured properly. On router you will also have to set the NAT appropriately - so that your port from your external IP is mapped to the appropriate port on your NAV server. (Check which port you have to map in "Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2015 Administration)
If you are not on your own network, but rather on corporate network this becomes more complicated, and would require much more details from your side.